# Find if QTreeWidgetItem is top level

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way I can find out if the `QTreeWidgetItem` I'm looking at is top level or not? I have a program crashing when I try to take the text of a parent if the item is top level (no parent).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html):

> The main difference between top-level
>   items and those in lower levels of the
>   tree is that a top-level item has no
>   *parent()*. This information can be used
>   to tell the difference between items,
>   and is useful to know when inserting
>   and removing items from the tree.

```
if (!node.parent()) {
    // top-level item
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you could check if the QTreeWidgetItem's parent is NULL.

```
const int FIRST_NODE_INDEX = 0;
QTreeWidget* pTreeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
pTreeWidget->setColumnCount(1);
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> ItemList;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ItemList.append(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(QString("item: %1").arg(i))));
}    
pTreeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, ItemList);

if(!ItemList.at(FIRST_NODE_INDEX)->parent())
{
    qDebug() << "is TopLevel";
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

```
treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item) > -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Top level items has no parent item.

```
bool isTopLevelItem( QTreeWidgetItem* aItem )
{
    return ( aItem->parent() == nullptr );
}
```

Or using a lambda function.

```
void function()
{
    // ...
    auto isTopLevel = []( QTreeWidgetItem* aItem ){ return ( aItem->parent() == nullptr ); };
    // ...

    if ( isTopLevel( item ) )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```